# Confusion about "transitive and intransitive verbs"

Tags: grammar

I must admit that I never thought anything about **transitive/intransitive verbs** might confound me like that. The problem appeared when I decided to dive into it a bit deeper and then I had to end up losing the thread completely.

**Transitive verb**, according to the rule, requires *subject+verb+object* form and should answer the question "**What**" or "**Whom**", while intransitive one sticks to "**subject+verb**" and takes no object, right? So how come in this sentence below *"**want**"* is accepted like intransitive verb? Please illuminate me as much as you can because I feel like I'm gradually going crazy.

> "***I want to be famous***".

I(subject) + want(verb) + to be famous(object). What do I want? I want to be famous. 
The same could be applied to

> "***I want you to become famous***"

Comment: If you look at this definition of **want** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/want, you will see that it has a [T] after the definition. That means that it is transitive.

Comment: [Verbs that can be followed by objects that are infinitive clauses include **agree, begin, decide, hope, intend, like, plan,** and **propose.** Not all the transitive verbs can use an infinite clause as object.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3077/126) I do not think *I want to live forever*, for example, qualifies as a transitive verb usage in the same way as, say, *I want **eternal life*** (which has an ordinary noun phrase as its object) or ditransitive *He gave me eternal life* (direct *and* indirect objects).

Comment: Looking at the example I've produced, could you say where I make mistakes, How should I look at it in order to have a proper grasp of it . I'm not looking for the definition of individual words, what I exactly need is to find any clue which will make it easy for me to absorb.

Comment: Cavid - I'm not sure it's helpful to classify an "infinitive clause" as an "object" for this context. Syntactically and semantically it's not at all the same as a normal object (an ordinary ***noun***, as in *I want **food***). You might get some help from [this page](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/Infinitive-Clause.htm) (I've just realized that the earlier answer I linked to above is simply cut&pasted from the link I've now included in *this* comment). Once you've got the general principle you can probably guess what "kind" of verbs can be used with an infinitive clause.

Comment: @CavidHummatov "Looking at the example I've produced, could you say where I make mistakes" -- One possible mistake is that you connect *what* and the answer to a *what*-question to the concept of "object". Consider this: "What is he doing?" "He's going to school." You wouldn't think that "(going) to school" is the object, right? -- IMHO, it's okay if you understand "to be famous" and "you to be famous" as an answer to the *what* in "What do you want?" intuitively (like a cheat sheet); however, it's unwise to overgeneralize the connection. (BTW, the formal grammar is a bit complicated.)

Comment: @Sina sorry , I really appreciate your effort in helping me get it but I couldn't really see any  substantial relevance to the matter in your  examples.

Answer (score 1):

**Want is a transitive verb in English and does not make sense if it is used without a direct object**.

Both of your examples have direct objects.

> I want to be famous.
>
> Direct object: "to be famous"

"To be famous" is an **infinitive phrase** and infinitive phrases are a sub-category of **noun phrases**.  Therefore, the entire phrase can be thought of as a noun.  As far as English is concerned, in the following sentences,

> I want to be famous
>
> I want a cat

"cat" and "to be famous" serve the same function.

In your second example, "to be famous" is still the direct object. "You" is something called the **indirect object**.